# update Index view with the data return in $.ajax success callback... Asp.Net Mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

i have a very simple "InddexView" which is showing the details of the entries which is already in the database. on the same view i have a create entry link. clicking the  create link using Ajax.Actionlink to update the div on the same "IndexView" and showing the create view with the textboxes and buttons... Now on the "Create" View.cshtml i am using the $.ajax to create new entries via ajax. entries are getting created in database but not refreshing the main "IndexView" to show the newly created entry.. please help on how to do that ?.

## Here is my _Create.Cshtml code which is used to disply all the entries.

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset id="fsShowCreatestatus">
            <legend>Entries</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Body)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Body)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" id="btnCreate" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btnCreate').click(function (e) {
            var title = $('#Title').val();
            var body = $('#Body').val();
            var postdata = {
                "Title": title,
                "Body": body
            };
            e.preventDefault();
            callajax(postdata);

        });

      function callajax(data) {
          $.ajax({
              url: '@Url.Action("CreateViaAjax","Home")',
              data: data,
              success: function (returnData) {
                  $('#divCreateNew').slideUp(100).fadeOut(50);
                  alert('Ajax-completed');
                  $('#divShowDetails').appendTo('#divEdit');
              },
              error: function (returndata) {
                  $('#divCreateNew').appendTo('#fsShowCreateStatus').html('there was an error while adding the entry');
              }
          });
        }
    </script>

here is my index view which the main view and using for showing partial view(_Create) and the link for creating the new one..
=======================================
<h2>Index</h2>
<div id="divCreateLink">
    <p>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Create New", "Create","Home", new AjaxOptions { 
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                HttpMethod = "GET",
                UpdateTargetId = "divCreateNew",

   })


    </p>
</div>

<div id="divCreateNew">

</div>

<div id="divEdit">

</div>

@Html.Partial("PartialCreate")
```

code gets executed but not refreshing the "IndexView"

seeking help...

## Here is my controller action "CreateViaAjax"

```
public ActionResult CreateViaAjax(Entries entries)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.DBEntries.Add(entries);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }

            return View(entries);
        }
```

## Here is my Index Action which return the Main View

```
public ViewResult Index()
        {

            return View(db.DBEntries.ToList());
        }
```

## here is my Create Action which is called when clciked on CreateEntry Link

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return PartialView("_Create");
        }
```

=================================

Comment: What are you returning from your controller action?

Comment: Also, what is the HTML markup for your current data in the database? A <ul> <table>???

Comment: Hi, i am getting the newly created entry in success call back and then i am hiding up the create div and which leads to details div sliding up with all the old entries...not with the new ones...

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of possibilities:

- Wrap the part that needs to be *refreshed* in a container and a partial view. Then once the entry is created, in the `success` callback, send another AJAX request to a controller action which will read the entries and return their refreshed state. When this AJAX call succeeds replace the container with the new contents: `$('#entriesContainer').html(result);`
- Because you have the info for the newly created entry in the success callback you could probably manually manipulate the html to append this new entry using `$('#entries').append('<li>new entry info</li>');`
- Reload the entire page without using AJAX : `window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';`

Comment: thx...i have updated the code. please have a look and let me know whts wrong... i am getting the newsly created entry in the return data in $.ajax success callback but in success i am hiding the create div and shoing the details div which is just sliding up with all the old entries  not with the newly created one...

Comment: @patel.milanb, the `CreateViaAjax` action that you are invoking with AJAX returns a partial view. It is this partial view that you need to inject into the DOM replacing the old contents. This should happen in the success callback of your callajax function. This function takes a `returnData` parameter and you do nothing with it. So you need to show this result somewhere, like: `$('#someResultContainer').html(returnData);`.

Comment: as you can see, the returnData reuturns all the index view content also the partial view content... so if i replace the contents in the main view in div, still its showing me the index view contents + the return data contents( which also have the index view contents) so its showing double time... i see that the data updated in main view by doing this ..

Comment: @patel.milanb, yes, that's the problem. Your `CreateViaAjax`, in case of success redirects to the Index action. This has to be modified so that it returns a `PartialView()` instead of redirecting.